# undefined method `nssm' for cookbook

Tags: jmeter, chef-infra, nssm

I am trying to install a jmeter service using nssm through cookbook.

but while running chef converge I am getting below error

FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `nssm' for cookbook: (chef-apply cookbook), recipe: (chef-apply recipe) :Chef::Recipe

here is the code

first I have installed the nssm to my local VM using below command in chef

```
  chocolatey_package 'nssm' do
    action    :install
    version  '2.24.101.20180116'
  end
```

then wants to install the jmeter service using nssm in chef

```
nssm 'jmeter_service' do
    program 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jmeter\tools\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter-server.bat'
    parameters(
      AppDirectory: 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jmeter\tools\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin',
      AppStdout: 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jmeter\tools\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\output.log',
      AppStderr: 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jmeter\tools\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\error.log',
      #AppRotateFiles: 1
    )
    action %i[install start]
  end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include relevant code from the cookbook/recipe in your question? A [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be ideal.

Comment: edit the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using [nssm supermarket cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nssm), and the failure seems to indicate that you are running `chef-apply`, that can only run a single recipe.

But since you are trying to use a custom resource from another cookbook, you need to:

1. Have a cookbook of your own
2. Have the `nssm` (and its dependent [windows](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/windows) cookbook) locally or on Chef server
3. Define the dependency for the `nssm` cookbook in your cookbooks `metadata.rb`
4. The `chocolatey_package` will install the `nssm` binary, which is different from `nssm 'something' do`

For an example of local setup:

1. Download the `nssm` and `windows` cookbooks from Supermarket to cookbooks path
2. Create another simple cookbook (e.g. `mycookbook`) with your recipe and `metadata.rb`
3. Define dependency in `metadata.rb`:

   ```
   depends 'nssm', '~> 4.0.1'
   ```
4. Optionally remove the `chocolatey_package` resource
5. Run your cookbook with `chef-client` or `chef-zero`

   ```
   chef-client -z -r recipe[mycookbook]
   ```